# Modeling time-based application in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

Im developing an auction style web app, where products are available for a certain period of time.

I would like to know how would you model that.

So far, what I've done is storing products in DB:

```
{
...
id: p001,
name: Product 1,
expire_date: 'Mon Oct 7 2013 01:23:45 UTC',
...
}
```

Whenever a client requests that product, I test *current_date < expire_date*.

If true, I show the product data and, client side, a countdown timer. If the timer reaches 0, I disable the related controls.

But, server side, there are some operations that needs to be done even if nobody has requested that product, for example, notify the owner that his product has ended.

I could scan the whole collection of products on each request, but seems cumbersome to me.

I thought on triggering a routine with cron every n minutes, but would like to know if you can think on any better solutions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Scanning the entire collection on each request sounds like a huge waste of processing time.

I would use something like [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to handle both keeping track of your main server process as well as running periodic tasks with its built-in cron-like functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

1. Index the `expire_date` field. You'll want to if you're scanning for auction items older than a certain date.
2. Consider adding a second field that is `expired` (or `active`) so you can also do other types of non-date searches (as you can always, and should anyway, reject auctions that have expired).
3. Assuming you add a second field `active` for example, you can further limit the scans to be only those auction items that are active and beyond the expiration date. Consider a compound index for those cases. (As over time, you'll have more an more expired items you don't need to scan through for example).
4. Yes, you should add a timed task using your favorite technique to scan for expired auctions. There are lots of ways to do this -- your infrastructure will help determine what makes sense.
5. Keep a local cache of current auction items in memory if possible to make scanning efficient as possible.  There's no reason to hit the database if nothing is expiring.
6. Again, always check when retrieving from the database to confirm that items are still active -- as there easily could be race conditions where expired items may expire while being retrieved for display.
7. You'll possible want to store the state of status e-mails, etc. in the database so that any server restarts, etc. are properly handled.

It might be something like:

```
{
...
id: p001,
name: "Product 1",
expire_date: ISODate("Mon Oct 7 2013 01:23:45 UTC"),
active: true,
...
}

// console
db.auctions.esureIndex({expire_date: -1, active: 1})

// javascript idea:
var theExpirationDate = new Date(2013, 10, 06, 0, 0, 0);
db.auctions.find({ expire_date : { "$lte" : theExpirationDate }, active: true })
```